# Android Notification at Specific Time

Tags: android, performance, push-notification

I'm developing a basic calendar application for Android, I keep events on Realm database. The table have 3 column which are id, title and start_time. I would like to send notification when event start_time is arrived. Alarm manager could be a solution, that get all events from database where start_time is equal to current time, and then generate notification for these events. But it may consuming battery too much. Is there any other solution for such cases.

Comment: You can use JobScheduler check the link https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling

Comment: I think JobScheduler is not the case for this situation, as you could find in documentation it only guarantees job is worked, but it not guarentees working time.